# No X server setitngs in nvidia-settings?

Tags: nvidia

I installed `nvidia-settings` to enable Vsync because when watching a video, my screen speed drops to 60 (from 144), but I did not find X server settings when I ran the `nvidia-settings` command:

os version Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

using default ubuntu

[image: nvidia-settings]

Comment: Was mixed up before, thinking there was an X server settings on the left side of screen. The X server info does appear on the right side, under the system info, when the X server runs instead of Wayland.  Selection made at login, under the cog which appears when your password field is visible ont he lower right of screen.

Comment: You're using wayland, the default in 22.04. It works with Nvidia graphics and the latest Nvidia graphics but it's still "experimental". Namely there are almost no settings at Nvidia X Server Settings as shown in your screenshot. Try the "old" X11 instead.